# Can't login/authorize gspread Python

Tags: python, gspread

not sure if i should have put this in a tuple but it says it only takes one argument

My code:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.authorize(("example@gmail.com", 'example_password'))
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'access_token'

Thanks in Advance : ]

Comment: check the docu, http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html, and use googles Oauth2 workflow to create the credentials

Answer (score 1):

Email authentication (aka ClientLogin) doesn't work any longer. It was deprecated by Google on April 20, 2015.

Ari's right. To authenticate with Google API you need to use oAuth2. Depending on your workflow (standalone script or a web service) you may need different strategies. For standalone scripts, one option is to use Signed Credentials.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to use them: http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html